# Configurar HTTPS em WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, https

Fiz um Web Service utilizando WebApi MVC5, com Visual Studio 2017. Está funcionando, mas como faço para utilizar HTTPS ao invés de HTTP? Alguém tem algum material pra eu pesquisar? Encontrei algumas coisas mas com WCF e não com Web Api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue link com 2 materiais bem interessantes sobre o assunto:

**Working with SSL in Web API**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api

e **Using SSL in ASP.NET Web API**

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/using-ssl-in-asp.net-web-api.htm

Abs.

Comment: Obrigado @Rodolpho!